# how to convert char[] to string&

Tags: c++, string, std

I have a method `setValue(string& val)` that I need to call for some default values.
I would like to call it like this:

```
setValue("");
setValue("random value");
```

but I get the following error with g++: `no matching function to call setValue(const char [10])`

any idea on how I can do this beside creating a temp string object ?
It works but I find it inconvenient:

```
string temp("random value");
setValue(temp);
```

Comment: If you write `const string&` instead of `string&`, it will work due to the constructor `string(const char*)` and array decay.

Comment: Presumably `setValue` takes a non-`const` reference because it wants to make observable changes to the string that you pass in. In that case don't you need a local `string` variable in any case in order to see the changes?

Comment: you sugestion is the answer for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `string&` will not bind to temporary objects, only to non const *named* objects (*non-const lvalues* in the Standard language). You'll have to name an object to pass to your function, as you do with the `temp` variable.

One workaround is to use a `const` reference to string and pass directly your string literal to it. This works because 1) `string` has a non-explicit constructor which accepts `const char*` 2) `const char [10]` will decay to `const char*`.

Answer (score 10):

Modify your function to take a `const string &`.

Comment: Passing a temporary by non-const reference is definitely not standard C++, at least not C++98.